# How to add a single element that depends on data inside *ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have an application in which I loop through an array of alertMessages. For each alertMessage I am checking if all the parameters is valid (the alertmessage is not marked as deleted, read etc) and that it has been created today. If all these parameters are not valid, I do not want to show the alertmessage.

But I also want to display an h2-element containing the word "Today". However, this h2 should only be shown once and only if alertmessages are rendered.

alerts-page.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let alertMessage of alertMessages$ | async">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let recipient of alertMessage.recipients">
    <ng-container *ngIf="parametersAreValid(recipient) && wasCreatedToday(alertMessage)">
      <alert [alertRecipient]="recipient [alertMessage]="alertMessage"> 
      </alert>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

alerts-page.component.ts

```
    parametersAreValid(alertRecipient: AlertRecipient): boolean {
        const isForCurrentUser = alertRecipient.recipientId === this.currentUser.id;
        const isNotMarkedAsDeleted = !alertRecipient.isDeleted;
        const isNotMarkedAsRead = !alertRecipient.isRead;
        const isShownWhenShowDeletedIsSetToTrue = (alertRecipient.isDeleted && this.showDeleted);
        const isShownWhenShowReadIsSetToTrue = (alertRecipient.isRead && this.showRead);
        return (isForCurrentUser) && (isShownWhenShowDeletedIsSetToTrue || isNotMarkedAsDeleted) &&
            (isNotMarkedAsRead || isShownWhenShowReadIsSetToTrue);
    }


    wasCreatedToday(alertMessage: AlertMessage): boolean {
        const today = moment();
        const alertSentAt = moment(alertMessage.sentAt);

        return moment(alertSentAt).isSame(today, 'day');

    }
```

Comment: Don't put all this logic in the view. Put it in the component. Filter out the array of alerts to create an array of alerts *to display*. Then, if the array of alerts *to display* is empty, don't display the heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ngLet directive of the ngrx-utils library.https://github.com/ngrx-utils/ngrx-utils 
With this directive you can store the allertmessages in a local variable in you template.
You can then check for alertMessages.lenght > 0 and display the h2 with an *ngIf directive.

However, I agree with Kamil that you should'nt put too much logic in the template